# Get return value from JS code to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to get the answer of a `window.prompt()` alert box through the C# Code Behind file. It's just a one-liner of JavaScript code, so I thought I could even execute it from the Code Behind file. It doesn't really matter to me whether it's a `<script>` tag in the `.aspx` file or executed through the `.aspx.cs` file.

I thought of having the script executed (called from the C# part) and then having the return value assigned to a certain not visible field, but is there any better way to do it?

The obvious way would probably go something like this:

```
.aspx file:
<script>
function foo() {
    document.getElementById('MyFieldID').value = window.prompt('Answer this question:', '');
}
</script>

.aspx.cs file:
////////////////////////////////////////////////
//MyFieldID.Text now contains whatever I want//
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

What do you say? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

*Better* way is always opinion based. What I'd say is you have a few options, all depend on what you're doing. HTTP and ASP.NET provide us a few means of sending data to the server, there are 3 main ones before HTML5:

1. Query string
2. Form values
3. AJAX calls

If you're redirecting the user to a new page after they answer the prompt, you can just send them to `yournewurl.aspx?promptAnswer=*whatever*`

If you're doing a postback, then you can use a form value (this looks like what you're doing in your example). You can put an `<asp:HiddenField>` on the page and populate it from JavaScript before submitting the form.

If you need just the prompt response, but are not attempting to reload the page, you can make an AJAX call that sends the variable to the server (this still uses #1 or #2 to send the data, it just does it without reloading the page).

Which of those three options works best depends on your implementation. However, your solution should work just fine. However, since the control you'd likely be using to stuff the value into is a `HiddenField` it would be in `MyFieldID.Value` not `MyFieldID.Text`. The only other thing you have to deal with is if your `MyFieldID` is nested in some other controls (like a `ContentPlaceHolder`) such that the ClientID has naming containers pretended to it so it's really something like `ContentPlanceHolder1_MyFieldID` when accessed from JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do not agree that it's subjective, though. Some things are but performance (what way takes less memory or whatever) is quite objective.

Comment: @Zim agreed. But it depends on your needs. If you want to provide the user with instant feedback and not reload the page, AJAX is the way to go. If you're already submitting a form for a postback, a hidden field is the way to go. If you're just redirecting, a query string is the way to go. My point is it's subjective because it depends on the situation. Since you didn't provide the situation I tried to provide examples covering different situations. If my answer doesn't cover your use case, please provide more details and is be glad to add more to my answer.